# How to conditionally update properties of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object named options. I need to do something like below where if a property is already set, update it otherwise don't do anything:

```js
if (options.A)
    options.A = formatMessage(options.A);
if (options.B)
    options.B = formatMessage(options.B);
if (options.C)
    options.C = formatMessage(options.C);
if (options.D)
    options.D = formatMessage(options.D);
```

Is there a better way to check if a particular property of an object is set and then update in pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over an array of key names - if the retrieved value at each key is truthy, call the function and reassign it:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].forEach((key) => {
  if (options[key]) {
    options[key] = formatMessage(options[key]);
  }
});
```

If these are the only keys that might exist, you might consider using `.reduce` into a new object instead, thereby avoiding unnecessary mutation:

```
const formattedOptions = Object.entries(options).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
  a[key] = formatMessage(val);
  return a;
}, {});
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this option

```js
 const obj = {
 'A':'test','B':'test1','C':'test2','D':'test3'
 };
    
 Object.keys(obj).map(key=> {
   obj[key]=formatMessage(obj[key]);
 });
 
 function formatMessage(msg){
 return msg + 'translated';
 }
 
 console.log(obj);
```